# Why does workbox registerRoute gets an opaque response, while precaching does not

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to precache jpg images with cachefirst strategy to avoid downloading them again and again.

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot use this, it doesn't work with `CacheFirst` (while it works with `StaleWhileRevalidate` and `NetworkFirst`)

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /.+\.jpg/, 

  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({ // OPAQUE -> only possibility = StaleWhileRevalidate or NetworkFirst. CacheFirst won't work
    cacheName: 'posters',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 500,
      })
    ],
  })
); // BUG: THIS SEEMS TO TAKE MORE SPACE THAN THE SUM OF IMAGES: 50 images of ~5kb -> 580 Mb
```

The `precaching` method of workbox works too

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(jpgList);
```

But I cannot use that because my list of jpg is big and dynamic (i.e. I do not know that list before the webapp is loaded.). I don't use the workbox CLI.

> --> I do not understand why `precaching` works while `.routing.registerRoute` doesn't?

---

TRIED:

I have tried to fill the `Cache Storage` from the web page JavaScript after the page was loaded with

```
window.caches.open( 'jpg-precache' )
  .then( cache => cache.addAll( jpgList ) )
```

and that works, but then the service worker doesn't know to use those assets with cachefirst.

Also the advantage of the `.routing.registerRoute` is that I don't have to list all jpg's, only the main ones, since all the new ones it will encounter will be cached.

---

EDIT:

I forgot something important: images are from a third party server e.g. https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/6ApDtO7xaWAfPqfi2IARXIzj8QS.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Workbox actually matches the regex for same server, if not typed in regex. The [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_regular_expression_route) Says:

> However, for cross-origin requests, regular expressions must match the beginning of the URL.

So the regex you're using should be something like - `https:\/\/image\.tmdb\.org.*\.jpg` instead of `.+\.jpg`.

Comment: Isn't the regex fine since it works ok with the `StaleWhileRevalidate` strategy ?. The regex I'm actually using is `/.+image\.tmdb\.org/`, but I don't see any difference between the 3, they all work the same with StaleWhileRevalidate

Comment: `.+` actually matches the the beginning of the URL.  I took this from https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests `new RegExp('.+\\.js$')`